# If $A_m \to I$, and $\alpha_m \to 0$, $\alpha_m \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\lVert A_m^{\lceil \frac{1}{\alpha_m} \rceil} - I\rVert < 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm looking at John Stilwell's Naive Lie Theory, page 146, Smoothness of sequential tangency. In it, he uses the identity $\log(A_m^{\alpha_m}) = \alpha_m \log(A_m)$. However, this implicitly assumes that $A_m^{\alpha_m}$ is in the domain of $\log$. Is this true?

We have $A_m \to I$, $A_m \in \mathbf{GL}(n; \mathbb{R})$ and $\alpha_m \to 0$, $\alpha_m \in \mathbb{R}$, and I believe we want to show that $\lVert A_m^{\lceil \frac{1}{\alpha_m} \rceil} - I\rVert < 1$ for large enough $m$. Any idea how to do this? It's easy enough to show that $\lVert A_m^{n} - I\rVert < 1$ for some fixed $n$ but I'm at a loss to show this holds when raising to the power of the sequence.

Comment: Well $\alpha_m \to 0$ so that above some $N$ your sequence becomes $\| A_m - I \|$ (or $\|I-I\|=0$ if we allow $\alpha_m$ to go negative.)

Comment: @Callum $\frac{1}{\alpha_m} \to \infty$

Comment: Oops I misread that as just $\alpha_m$

Comment: What you want to show in the second paragraph is wrong in all dimensions $n$. For $n=1$, take $A_m := \sqrt[m]{17}$ and $a_m =1/m$. Then $A_m^{\lceil \frac{1}{a_m}\rceil}$ is constantly $17$. With $a_m=1/m^2$ you can make it diverge to infinity, far away from $1$. For higher dimensions $n$, take the diagonal matrix with such entries.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thanks, nice counter example. I guess the proof in the book is wrong without some further restrictions on the sequences.